# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n^{n}}{e^{n} n!}=x_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n^{n}}{e^{n} n!}=x_{n}$$

I tried to use the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}\right)^{n} <1$ then the limit is $0$

I got $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^{n}(n+1)e}\right)^{n}$ How to continue ?

Comment: [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) seems a good place to start.

Comment: As a general note:  It's bad notation to call that limit $x_n$, as the limit can not in fact depend on $n$.  I assume you meant to write $x_n=\frac {n^n}{e^nn!}$ and then ask about $\displaystyle {\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n}$, but that's not what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

So you have: 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg( \frac{(n+1)^{n+1} }{n^n(n+1)e } \bigg)^n  $$
Then you can continue by doing the following:
$$ \bigg( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^{n+1} }{n^n(n+1)e } \bigg)^n
 =  \bigg( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)(n+1)^{n} }{n^n(n+1)e } \bigg)^n 
=\bigg( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{e } \bigg[\frac{n+1}{n}\bigg]^n \bigg)^n 
= \bigg( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{e } \bigg[1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigg]^n \bigg)^n
= \bigg(  \frac{1}{e } \lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg[1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigg]^n \bigg)^n
=\bigg(  \frac{1}{e } e\bigg)^n = 1
$$
So i guess the ratio test is inconclusive in this case...